# Spring Batch Oracle TIMESTAMP Jackson serialization failure

Tags: jackson, spring-batch

I use a JDBC paging item reader where one of the sort keys (submitteddate) in the query provider is defined as a timestamp column in the Oracle table. After migration from Spring batch 3 to 4 (via Spring Boot 5.1), I now get this exception:

> Caused by:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No
>   serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no
>   properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception,
>   disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference
>   chain:
>   java.util.HashMap["AbstractPagingItemReader.start.after"]>java.util.LinkedHashMap[""submitteddate""]>oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP["stream"])
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:313)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serializeWithType(UnknownSerializer.java:45)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:729)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeWithType(BeanSerializerBase.java:604)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeTypedFields(MapSerializer.java:933)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:688)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeWithType(MapSerializer.java:666)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeWithType(MapSerializer.java:33)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeTypedFields(MapSerializer.java:933)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:688)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:639)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:33)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3905)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:3176)
>   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.serialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:78)
>   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.serialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:50)
>   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.serializeContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:299)
>   ... 30 common frames omitted

I have been reading about the default serializer switch from xstream to jackson as the cause of this. What are my options? Should I go back to using the xstream serializer? Should I write a jackson oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP serializer? The latter option is not good as this is Oracle specific would require me to distribute a licensed jar. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I went with the solution provided [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonmappingexception#1-globally-auto-detect-fields-with-any-visibility) since oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP does not expose any public getter/setter. Had to upgrade spring batch to 4.2 as the Jackson2 serializer is not open for configuration in 4.1 due [to](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/786).