# Spring Batch No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream for oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-batch, objectmapper

I use Spring Batch and has a job definition. I can successfully fetch data from db but my job fail after trying to process first chunk.

I have a `JdbcPagingItemReader` and has a sort definition for a date field:

```
    Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>();
    sortKeys.put("MY_DT", Order.ASCENDING);

    OraclePagingQueryProvider queryProvider = new OraclePagingQueryProvider();
    queryProvider.setSelectClause("---");
    queryProvider.setFromClause("FROM ---");
    queryProvider.setWhereClause("WHERE MY_DT >= :myDt");
```

However I get this error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["JdbcPagingItemReader.start.after"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["MY_DT"]->oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP["stream"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1277)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serializeWithType(UnknownSerializer.java:45)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:730)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeWithType(BeanSerializerBase.java:640)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeTypedFields(MapSerializer.java:941)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:696)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeWithoutTypeInfo(MapSerializer.java:681)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeWithType(MapSerializer.java:650)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeWithType(MapSerializer.java:33)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeTypedFields(MapSerializer.java:941)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:696)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeWithoutTypeInfo(MapSerializer.java:681)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeWithType(MapSerializer.java:650)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeWithType(MapSerializer.java:33)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.TypeWrappedSerializer.serialize(TypeWrappedSerializer.java:32)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._writeValueAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4409)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:3621)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.serialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:141)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.serialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.serializeContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:302)
```

I think that problem is related to `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP` does not have a public constructor. So, if I change my sort parameter into a non-date type everything works like a charm. However, I couldn't make it work with date sorting even I try to customize object mapper.

Any ideas?

**PS:** As a workaround, I've tried this which didn't work:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
        simpleModule.addSerializer(TIMESTAMP.class, new OracleTimestampSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
        mapper.setVisibility(mapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
                .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
        return mapper;
    }

    private static class OracleTimestampSerializer extends JsonSerializer<TIMESTAMP> {
        @Override
        public void serializeWithType(oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP timestamp, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers, TypeSerializer typeSerializer) throws IOException {
            WritableTypeId typeId = typeSerializer.writeTypePrefix(gen, typeSerializer.typeId(timestamp, JsonToken.VALUE_EMBEDDED_OBJECT));
            serialize(timestamp, gen, serializers);
            gen.writeTypeSuffix(typeId);
            throw new RuntimeException("Error!");
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP timestamp, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) {
            try {
                gen.writeBinary(timestamp.getBytes());
                throw new RuntimeException("Error!");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("serialize oracle.sql.Timestamp error :" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, that runtime exceptions are not thrown too.

Comment: This helpful?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60381349/spring-batch-oracle-timestamp-jackson-serialization-failure

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'll update the question with my workaround code which is related to that  question.

Answer (score 1):

From the stacktrace you shared, I see that the issue happens when the execution context is being serialized. And indeed, this is due to the default Jackson mapper not knowing how to (de)serialize timestamps. Supplying a custom mapper is the way to go. However, to do so, you would need to provide a custom `JobRepository` through `JobRepositoryFactoryBean#setSerializer` with your custom implementation. Just declaring the serializer as a bean in the application context is not sufficient (We are planning to improve this [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3942), please upvote or comment on that issue if you are interested). You can find more details about how to customize the job repository in the [Configuring a JobRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/job.html#configuringJobRepository) section.

In your case, you would need to provide a custom `BatchConfigurer` (or extend `DefaultBatchConfigurer`) and implement `getJobRepository` (or override `createJobRepository`), something like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfigWithCustomSerializer {

    @Bean
    public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
                Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer serializer = new Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer();
                // customize serializer
                serializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
                JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
                factory.setSerializer(serializer);
                // set other properties on the factory bean
                factory.afterPropertiesSet();
                return factory.getObject();
            }
        }
    }

}
```